# Perplexing Excel reference behavior on column insert

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a worksheet with seven columns of integers (A through G), two descriptive columns (H and I), and three columns (J through L) performing COUNT functions and other math. Periodically I will need to add a new column to the first group.

My question: I would like the formulas in the last group (J, K, L) to expand their formulas' ranges to include the new column automatically, e.g. =SUM(A2:G2) becomes =SUM(A2:H2) on column insert. The only way this seems to work is if I insert the new column in the midst of the others. If I try to insert to the left of A or to the right of G, the ranges in the formulas do not expand. I've tried playing with mixed references without success. Fool's errand? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

That is normal behavior.
The best way to 'append' a column is to copy the last one ('G'), and insert it right before it (between 'F' and 'G'); then overwrite the data in the rightmost column with the new data.

Comment: Does that 'trick' also work for expanding the formula when it's row ranges rather than column ranges (copy last row and insert it above itself)?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I've been doing it that way for years. All Excel versions. My fingers know it by heart: CTRL+C, ALT+I, E.